# How to filter and classify data in Angular 14

Tags: angular, filter

I want to see P status and step 01 when I press All
and its type . thank a lot

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
               <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of typeOptions">
                    {{item}}
                </mat-option> 
            </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

typescript.
what did i miss

```
this.prhd.getPr_prhds()
      .subscribe({
        next: data => {  
          his.dataSource.data = data.filter(s => s.status === 'P' && s.stap === '01')
            this.apiResponse = data
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
            this.typeOptions= _.uniq(data.map( (item:any) => item['type']))          
             this.typeOptions = ["All"].concat(this.typeOptions)
        }
```

function change type.
typescript

```
onChange($event:any){
    if($event.value.toLowerCase()=="all"){
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.apiResponse);
    } else {
      let filteredData = _.filter(this.apiResponse,(item) =>{
        return item.type.toLowerCase() ==  $event.value.toLowerCase();
      })
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(filteredData);
    }
   
  }
```

example json

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "aaaa",
"status": "P",
"step": "01",
"type": "01"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "bbbb",
"status": "P",
"step": "01",
"type": "01"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "cccc",
"status": "O",
"step": "02",
"type": "02"
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "dddd",
"status": "O",
"step": "02",
"type": "02"
}]
```

But by default I can do it.

[image]

This is when I press ALL

[image]

i don't want status O

This is now pressing its type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not removing the `status='O'` when `type=all` is selected. You have to make this change inside the `onChange` function.

```
onChange($event:any){
  let filteredData = _.filter(this.apiResponse,(item) =>{
      return item.status !== "0";
  });
  if ($event.value.toLowerCase() !== "all") {
     filteredData = _.filter(filteredData,(item) =>{
        return item.type.toLowerCase() ==  $event.value.toLowerCase();
     })
  }
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(filteredData);
}
```

Comment: wow you help me to do "all" thank you so much i left the categorization of it I don't know how to write it.

Comment: @okmmy123456 I don't get you, what exactly do you mean here?

Comment: I pressed type 3 as in the picture, o must not show.

Comment: @okmmy123456 can you please clarify the expected behavior please?

Comment: I also have type 01 02 where it also shows type o

Comment: @okmmy123456 do you want to completely get rid of `status=0` when any specific category is selected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247273/discussion-between-okmmy123456-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: yes i want to get rid of `status=0`

Comment: @okmmy123456 check updated answer